# React native passing a picker item data between components

Tags: react-native

i am a beginner with react native. I m trying to pass a selected item from picker to another component after verifying either that item is equal to the value in mysql database.

Here's my code:

```
<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.language}
  style={styles.picker}
  onValueChange={(lang) => this.setState({language: lang})}
    <Picker.Item label="english" value="english" />
    <Picker.Item label="french" value="french" />
</Picker>
```

Anyone could help please?

Comment: What have you tried, share some code? With this description you will only receive general guesses and vague answers which do not solve your actual problem.

Comment: <Picker selectedValue={this.state.language}
          style={styles.picker} 
         onValueChange={(lang) => this.setState({language: lang})}>
          <Picker.Item label="english" value="english" /> 
          <Picker.Item label="french" value="french" />
          </Picker> and i have a button function for redirection to new component

Answer (score 0):

There are predefined ways to use value of a picker. The one I can suggest you is

```
<Picker 
 selectedValue={this.state.language} 
 style={styles.picker}   
 onValueChange={
    (itemValue, itemIndex) => 
     this.setState({ 
     PickerValue: itemValue,
     language: itemValue
  })                    
 }
>
<Picker.Item label="english" value="english" />
<Picker.Item label="french" value="french" />
</Picker>
```

itemValue & itemIndex are predefined arguments in Picker for picking Picker.Item value and key.